# mail sends several time the same email

Tags: centos, roundcube

I have install the latest version of vestaCP (0.9.8-12) with Centos 6.6 and the following mail packages:
roundcubemail-1.0.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
mailcap-2.1.31-2.el6.noarch
mailx-12.4-7.el6.x86_64

My problem is that each time I use the mail() function, it sends 7/10 email to the same recipient instead of one. Is there anything to do?

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by a reinstallation of VestaCP (newer version).